# Angular scope deleted on splice

Tags: javascript, angularjs, splice

When trying to remove an item from a list using splice, my entire list is destroyed? what could be cause it?

HTML:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">
      <a href="" ng-click="select(pane)">
          {{pane.title}}&nbsp;
          <sup ng-click="close(pane)">x</sup>
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a href="" ng-click="createPane()">+</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

JS

```
.controller('editCtrl', ['$scope', function($scope){

    $scope.panes = [];
    var ctrl  = this;
    /*===========Select===========*/
    $scope.select = function(pane) {
      angular.forEach($scope.panes, function(pane) {
        pane.selected = false;
      });
      pane.selected = true;
    };
    /*==========Add-Pane=========*/
    this.addPane = function(pane) {
      if ($scope.panes.length === 0) {
        $scope.select(pane);
      }
      $scope.panes.push(pane);
    };
    /*===========Create===========*/
    $scope.createPane = function() {
        var pane = {
            title: 'untitled',
            content: 'Scope:'+$scope.$id
        }
        ctrl.addPane(pane);
    };
    /*===========Close===========*/
    $scope.close = function(pane) {
        var idx = $scope.panes.indexOf(pane);
        //$scope.panes.splice(pane, 1);
        if (idx != -1) $scope.panes.splice(idx, 1); 
    }
}]);
```

in particular I am looking at the close method, The rest work fine.

Comment: The line that you commented out is the correct syntax.

Comment: It does the same thing; it deletes all of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your list isn't destroyed by anything.

But the `href=""` on those `<a>` tags make the entire page to be refreshed when clicking the `x` icon.

Try removing those `href` like this:

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
  <li ng-repeat="pane in panes" ng-class="{active:pane.selected}">
      <a ng-click="select(pane)">
          {{pane.title}}&nbsp;
          <sup ng-click="close(pane)">x</sup>
      </a>
  </li>
  <li>
      <a ng-click="createPane()">+</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: That was the problem. Awesome catch!

Answer (score 0):

You're already passing the index of the pane you want to remove when you send `$index` as the parameter to your `close($index)` function.

Thus your close function should look like this:

```
$scope.close = function(i){
    var removedPane = $scope.panes.splice(i,1);
    // do something here with the "removedPane" if you want to
};
```

This line

```
var idx = $scope.panes.indexOf(pane);
```

is trying to find the index of the index being sent to the function, thus `idx` is most likely undefined.

**EDIT**

You need to go back to calling close like this:

```
`ng-click="close($index)"`
```